# Connect to external MongoDB database from MeteorJs application on Windows

Tags: windows, mongodb, meteor

Hopefully this is a newbie question.
I am trying to connect to an external MongoDB database from MeteorJs application on Windows. I am however getting a "Authentication failed" error. I have set the Env:MONGO_URL using powershell and I am then running the meteor command on the command prompt. I am however able to connect to the same database using a client tool(Studio 3T)

```
$Env:MONGO_URL='mongodb://<userId>:<password>@<host>/<databaseName>'
```

What am I missing?

**Stack Trace:**

```
W20190915-18:32:25.554(-5)? (STDERR) C:\Users\AjitGoel\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.8.1\mt-os.windows.x86_64\dev_bundle\server-lib\node_modules\fibers\future.js:313
W20190915-18:32:25.557(-5)? (STDERR)                                            throw(ex);
W20190915-18:32:25.560(-5)? (STDERR)                                            ^
W20190915-18:32:25.564(-5)? (STDERR)
W20190915-18:32:25.569(-5)? (STDERR) MongoError: Authentication failed.
W20190915-18:32:25.571(-5)? (STDERR)     at C:\Users\AjitGoel\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\npm-mongo\3.1.2\npm\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:581:63
W20190915-18:32:25.574(-5)? (STDERR)     at authenticateStragglers (C:\Users\AjitGoel\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\npm-mongo\3.1.2\npm\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:504:16)
W20190915-18:32:25.578(-5)? (STDERR)     at Connection.messageHandler (C:\Users\AjitGoel\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\npm-mongo\3.1.2\npm\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:540:5)
W20190915-18:32:25.580(-5)? (STDERR)     at emitMessageHandler (C:\Users\AjitGoel\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\npm-mongo\3.1.2\npm\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:310:10)
W20190915-18:32:25.584(-5)? (STDERR)     at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\AjitGoel\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\npm-mongo\3.1.2\npm\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:453:17)
W20190915-18:32:25.588(-5)? (STDERR)     at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
W20190915-18:32:25.590(-5)? (STDERR)     at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
W20190915-18:32:25.594(-5)? (STDERR)     at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
W20190915-18:32:25.598(-5)? (STDERR)     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
W20190915-18:32:25.600(-5)? (STDERR)     at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
W20190915-18:32:25.602(-5)? (STDERR)     at TCP.onread (net.js:601:20)
=> Exited with code: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get my meteorjs application working by creating a new MONGO_URL environment variable under “system variables” instead of using Powershell to create an environment variable.

Comment: Declaring a system variable like this will work, but there are other (possibly more elegant) ways. Have a look at the npm module `cross-env`, which will allow you to provide environment variables as needed.